# Draw a line in Open GL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'd like to quickly draw a line of some fixed color given two points that I can change at will.

I have some other objects that I've got shaders and textures on that I could take code snippets on but they have way more code than I think is necessary for a simple line. I'm fairly new to Open GL ES 2.0 and I cant figure out how to just put a yellow 3D line on my screen without making some holder object.

this is in my onDrawFrame method of my renderer

```
    private void drawTestLine() {
       float[] lineEndPoints = new float[6];
       System.arraycopy(nearPoint, 0, lineEndPoints , 0, nearPoint.length);
       System.arraycopy(farPoint, 0, lineEndPoints , 3, farPoint.length);

//need help here
       GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_posL;
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix*vec4(a_posL,1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_lineColor;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = u_lineColor;
}
```

once you have these shaders, just pass position, color and matrix using glVertexAttribPointer and glUniforms

Comment: I'll try that, I was hoping to avoid making a new program for just a line but it looks like I must.